# WebApi ActionFilterAttribute controller property and Ninject dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a problem where i need to pass in a parameter from the controller attribute but i also want a dependency to be DI'ed into the attribute so that i can use it in conjunction with the parameter passed into the attribute.

I currently have this working using the [Inject] attribute on the public property inside the class. Is it possible to have this injected without the [Inject] decorator. I have seen numerous post regarding setting this up where your not passing in parameter from the controller, but i haven't been able to get a sample where you can do both.

I'm using Ninject at the DI container

My attribute looks like this

```
public class AccessActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    private readonly string[] _permissions;
    public AccessActionFilter(string[] permissions)
    {
        _permissions = permissions;
    }

    [Inject]
    public IUserService UserService { private get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //... custom logic here
        var hasPermissons = UserService.HasPermission(string[] permissions);
        ...
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }

    public override bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

My Controller code code looks like this

```
    Controller Code

[AccessActionFilter(new []{"UpdateDocument"})].
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(PostedModel model)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this approach by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/). Your attribute is added as a global filter, taking any dependencies in the constructor, and will only perform its work if the action executed has another passive attribute

Comment: And also take a look at [this related approach](http://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=98).

Comment: Thanks all, both approaches look fairly similar and both look like they will achieve what i want. I just need some time to fit these into my solution with ninject.